# Vue.js Не получается отрисовать данные в компонент полученные из json в

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Есть файл JSON в котором находятся продукты с уникальной категорией. Необходимо эти продукты отрисовать на странице соответствующей категории. Сами же категории находятся в хранилище store в заданном объекте (categories) 
Вот код из хранилища

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m))
const categories = [
  {
    id: 'checktape57',
    cTitle: 'Чековая лента',
    cName: 'Чековая лента 57мм',
    cSlug: 'checktape57',
    cMetaDescription: 'Мета описание',
    cDesc: 'Описание',
    products: []

  },
  {
    id: 'checktape',
    cTitle: 'Чековая лента',
    cName: 'Чековая лента 80мм',
    cSlug: 'check80',
    cMetaDescription: 'Мета описание',
    cDesc: 'Описание',
    products: []

  },
  {
    id: 'checktape',
    cTitle: 'Чековая лента',
    cName: 'Чековая лента 44мм',
    cSlug: 'check44',
    cMetaDescription: 'Мета описание',
    cDesc: 'Описание',
    products: []

  },

  {
    id: 'checktape',
    cTitle: 'Чековая лента',
    cName: 'Лента для банкоматов',
    cSlug: 'checktape',
    cMetaDescription: 'Мета описание',
    cDesc: 'Описание',
    products: []

  },

  {
    id: 'termolabel',
    cTitle: 'Термоэтикетки',
    cName: 'Термоэтикетки',
    cSlug: 'termolabel',
    cMetaDescription: 'Мета описание',
    cDesc: 'Описание',
    products: []
  }
]



function addProductsToCategory (products, category) {
  const categoryInner = { ...category, products: [] }
  category.products.map(p => {
    if (p.category_id === category.id) {
      categoryInner.products.push({
        id: p.id,
        pName: p.pName,
        pSlug: p.pSlug,
        pPrice: p.pPrice
      })
    }
  })
  console.log(products)
  return categoryInner

}

export const state = () => ({
  categoriesList: [],
  currentCategory: {},
  currentProduct: {}
})
export const mutations = {
  SET_CATEGORIES_LIST (state, categories) {
    state.categoriesList = categories
  },
  SET_CURRENT_CATEGORY (state, category) {
    state.currentCategory = category
  },
  SET_CURRENT_PRODUCT (state, product) {
   state.currentProduct = product
  }
}
export const actions = {
  async getCategoriesList ({ commit }) {
    try {
      await sleep()
      await commit('SET_CATEGORIES_LIST', categories)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw new Error('Внутреняя ошибка сервера, сообщите администратору')
    }
  },
  async getCurrentCategory ({ commit }, { route }) {
    await sleep()
    const category = categories.find((cat) => cat.cSlug === route.params.CategorySlug)
    const products = await axios.get('/mock/products.json')
    await commit('SET_CURRENT_CATEGORY', addProductsToCategory(products, category))

  }

}
```

в Network json файл приходит
но на страницу не отрисовываются продукты:

```
 <div v-for="product in category.products" :key="product.id">
    <ProductBrief :product="product"/>
 </div>
```

и если выводить в консоль содержимое category.products , то он пуст. Помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю что я упустил

Comment: @gregman вот код компонента    <template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nuxt-link :to="`/product/${product.pSlug}`">
      <p>{{ product.pName }}</p>

    </nuxt-link>
    <p>Цена {{ product.pPrice }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Что будет если в шаблон вывести `{{category.products}}` над

> `<div v-for="product in category.products" :key="product.id">`
>   ?

Если там пусто как и в консле, значит данный не приходят в компонент.
Здесь нужно смотреть как "доставку" данных.

Здесь нет фрагмента компонента где получаются данные. 
Можешь обновить свой вопрос тогда станет яснее.